# PHP mysqli_fetch_all results nested in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to get all tables from a certain database inside an array, so I can compare it to another database.

```
//Get a list of all tables
$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM Data;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck == 0)
{
    exit("NO SQL RESULTS");
}

$array = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
print_r($array);
```

However, when I do this, it results in me getting an array with the results nested inside another array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => table1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => table2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => table3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => table4
        )
)
```

Is there a way of doing this, without using a while loop in combination with mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT group_concat(table_name) as tables FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='Data'
```

This will return a single field ***tables*** which contains a comma separated list of all table names.

You can then use:

```
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$tables = explode(",", $array['tables']);
print_r($tables);
```

To split the table names into an array